# GET or POST request => very long URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I'm creating a dynamic query in postgresql to filter a resultset.

I pass the parameters in the URL, an example is:

```
http://www.myurl.com/search?query=hello+word&sortorder=relevance&date=week&categories=cat1,cat2
```

The problem is, when a user selects a lot of categories (and other parameters that aren't included in the example URL), the URL will be very, very long. I'm using UUIDv4 for ID's so a lot of UUIDv4's are in the URL, separated by comma's.
Is it a better idea to do this with a POST request?

EDIT:

I'm using [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) to check if the incoming parameters are valid UUIDv4 (or numbers, ... whatever I need for that parameter to be).

I'm using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) to execute queries. This supports prepared statements, but I have NO CLUE how to use prepared statements with dynamic queries.

My SELECT code now looks like this (simplified):

```
const { featured, order } = req.body;

// featured
let featuredQuery = '';

if (featured !== undefined && validator.isBoolean(featured.toString())) {
  let featuredQuery = ` AND featured = ${featured}`;
}

// order
let orderQuery = 'timestamp DESC';

if (order !== undefined) {
  switch (order) {
    default:
    case 'date':
        orderQuery = 'timestamp DESC';
    break;
    case 'user_id':
        orderQuery = 'user_id DESC';
    break;
  }
}


const query = `
  SELECT
    name,
    description
  FROM
    users
  WHERE
    active = true
    ${featuredQuery}
  ORDER BY
    ${orderQuery}
`;
```

As you can see, I'm not passing prepared statements ($1, $2, ...) to the query but I'm using template literals. I have NO CLUE how to use prepared statements to add/delete where clauses.

Is there a safer way to do this?

EDIT 2: parameters are not containing sensitive information. I pass the user ID in the authorization header as a JWT.

Comment: Are you allowing your users to run any query to your database directly from your front-end?

Comment: I'm creating an IOS app so the URL is not in the browser visible to users, but in the code. I'm dynamically building the URL in the app with the selections the user makes.

Comment: Anyway, yes, that's what a simple POST request passing a data object is for.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer, I'll change my code.

Comment: @Jeremy POST has a very different semantic meaning from GET, and has implications on caching and browser history and such. It's *not* simply a replacement for long URLs.

Comment: Does it? I never knew that, I'm going to research it

Answer (score 2):

If you're fetching the contents of your parameter-laden URL using a program, not a browser, long GET URLs don't matter very much. (In browsers they're ugly.) For best results, and less testing burden on various legacy proxy servers etc, do your best to keep your URL length to 2000 octets or less. (Payload size for POST requests has no such limitation.)

Beware that URLs get logged. So, if your parameters carry any sensitive information you should consider using POST rather than GET.  Otherwise your users' sensitive information will land in your web server logs, presenting a juicy target for cybercreeps.

And, please please read up on SQL injection. Please please sanitize your incoming parameters before handing them off to your database server. Remember that cybercreeps can (and will) hit your URL from their malicious programs and try all sorts of combinations trying to break in.

[image]

Comment: I have added an edit about your concerns. Maybe you can help me by answering it. It's about SQL injection. Thank you for your answer btw!

Comment: Here's a writeup. Ask another question .... https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query  Post a link to the question here....